# constructor makes the object but doesn't assign values to it

Tags: c++, tree, binary-search-tree

I'm writing a binary search tree to hold the values of polynomial. The only problem that I have is making a leaf with 2 parameter ( coefficient , power of the x).

```
    tree newTree(5,2)    ;5(x^2)
    tree anothertree()   ;it works then I can insert leaf into the root
```

constructor makes the root but it is empty when I want to print the tree.

this is my constructor that accept 2 values to make a Node for a tree.

```
tree::tree(const int& c,const int& x)
{
    treeNode* root = new treeNode(c,x);
}
```

this is the Node struct that I use to make the Nodes for the tree.

```
        struct treeNode
       {
        int x;
        int coef;
        treeNode* left;
        treeNode* right;
        treeNode()
        {
            this->x=0;
            this->coef=0;
            this->left=nullptr;
            this->right=nullptr;
        }
        treeNode(const int& c,const int& x)
        {
            this->x = x;
            this->coef = c;
            left = nullptr;
            right = nullptr;
        }
    };
```

this is the class that I am working on:

```
 class tree{
    private:
    treeNode* root;
     void postorder(treeNode* p);
     void inorder(treeNode* p);
     void preorder(treeNode* p);
     void destroyTree(treeNode* p);
     void copyTree(treeNode* original,treeNode* &copycat);

public:
    tree();
    tree(const int& c,const int& x);
    tree(const tree& myTree);
    ~tree();
    void insert(int c,int xval);
    const tree & operator=(const tree &myTree);
    void print_postorder();
    void print_inorder();
    void print_preorder();
 };
```

Comment: `tree anothertree()   ;it works` - hmmm, this declares a _function_ returning a `tree`, not a `tree` object. Does it really work as you intend?

Comment: @Charles Bailey It makes a default tree with a null root .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tree::tree(const int& c,const int& x)
{
    treeNode* root = new treeNode(c,x);
}
```

`root` will go out of scope as soon as your constructor is done (and will leak the memory you just allocated).

You have `treeNode* root;` declared as a member of your `tree` class, what you need is:

```
tree::tree(const int& c,const int& x)
{
    root = new treeNode(c,x);
}
```

or

```
tree::tree(const int& c,const int& x) : root(new treeNode(c,x))
{
}
```

Note:  You will also need to free that memory in your destructor and anytime you change the memory location `root` points to.  Wrapping it in a `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` would be a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

root will go out of scope after your constructor exits.

You need to declare a global root pointer and initialise it in your constructor.

Comment: It does'nt need to be global. I think he should be declaring it as part of tree class.

Comment: that's true, the key is to persist it beyond constructor invocation